# Unable to get Service Fabric PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, powershell-5.0

I am running on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and I am not able to get the Service Fabric commandlets like Connect-ServiceFabricCluster.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/?view=azureservicefabricps) says : The Service Fabric PowerShell module is installed with the Service Fabric SDK, runtime, and tools.

- I am using visual studio 2019
- I followed instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started) and I have uninstalled and reinstalled Service Fabric SDK from Web Platform Installer and rebooted my system.

What else can I try? It is working in other system where I am using Windows 10. Can I export the module from another system where it is working and import it here?

Comment: what do you get with `Get-Command *Fabric* -All`, does it list anything?

Comment: It lists different commandlets from modules Az.ServiceFabric and AzureRm.ServiceFabric. In the working system, it is also getting from module ServiceFabric I am interested in(all the commandlets listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/?view=azureservicefabricps)).

Comment: I tried all the suggestions, but I still have to load the ServiceFabric PowerShell module manually when I start PowerShell. I am also getting this  WARNING: Module servicefabric is loaded in Windows PowerShell using WinPSCompatSession remoting session; please note that all input and output of commands from this module will be deserialized objects. If you want to load this module into PowerShell please use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you have installed the service fabric sdk; I tried it myself and able to find Connect-ServiceFabricCluster in the list. I can suggest two easiest ways to get it installed.

**A. with Choco package**

```
choco install MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK --source webpi --confirm
```

**B. With individual installation**

> **Install visual c++ 2012 SP1 redistributable package**
>
> Invoke-WebRequest
>   "http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU1/vcredist_x64.exe"
>   -OutFile "C:\vcredist.exe" -UseBasicParsing; \
>       Start-Process "C:\vcredist.exe" -ArgumentList '/install', '/passive' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
>       rm "C:\vcredist.exe"
>
> **Install Service Fabric Runtime**
>
> Invoke-WebRequest
>   "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/1/3217654F-6882-4CEA-BD51-49287EDECE9B/MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.0.232.9494.exe"
>   -OutFile "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe" -UseBasicParsing; \
>       Start-Process "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe" -ArgumentList '/AcceptEULA', '/QUIET' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
>       rm "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe"
>
> **Install Service Fabric SDK**
>
> Invoke-WebRequest
>   "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/1/3217654F-6882-4CEA-BD51-49287EDECE9B/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.8.232.msi"
>   -OutFile "C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi" -UseBasicParsing; \
>       Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi', '/passive', '/quiet', '/norestart', '/qn'
>   -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
>       rm "C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi"

**Here's the output**

```
$> Get-Command *ServiceFabricCluster* -All
```

[image]

Comment: I did B and also **Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser** it worked

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using PowerShell 7.x as my default version of PowerShell. Apparently, the ServiceFabric PowerShell module is only partly compatible with that version, so it is not loaded automatically. Once I used PowerShell 5.x to administer ServiceFabric, the module loaded upon PowerShell start and was ready to be used.

Comment: Same here. I used `Import-Module ServiceFabric -UseWindowsPowerShell` to import it via [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.1) .

Comment: @devmb thank you, this was the only place I could find this solution